# Save Selected Sheets in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Wondering why I can't do :

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name <> "DO NOT SAVE" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Select Replace:=False
Next i

Selection.Copy
```

what would be the best way to save all sheets which does not match DO NOT SAVE name in another wb ?

Comment: Store the sheet names in an array, then select after looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), i As Long
    ReDim arr(0 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "DO NOT SAVE" Then
            arr(i) = ws.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws
    Worksheets(arr).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: I just did as BigBen told me. and it went fine. But nice proposal

Comment: @TourEiffel - this is even better, because there's no need to Select actually (my brain fart)

Answer (score 3):

### A Reflection on the Sheets' Visibility

- To export a single sheet to a new workbook, the sheet has to be visible.
- To export multiple sheets (using an array of sheet names) to a new workbook, at least one of the sheets has to be visible, while very hidden sheets will not get exported (no error though).
- In a given workbook, the following procedure will copy all its sheets, except the ones whose names are in a given array (`Exceptions`), to a new workbook if at least one of the sheets is visible.
- Before copying, it will 'convert' the very hidden sheets to hidden and after the copying, it will 'convert' the originals and copies to very hidden.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSheets( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal Exceptions As Variant)
    
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    Dim SheetNames() As String: ReDim SheetNames(1 To shCount)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim coll As Object
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim VisibleFound As Boolean
    Dim VeryHiddenFound As Boolean
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            Select Case sh.Visible
            Case xlSheetVisible
                If Not VisibleFound Then VisibleFound = True
            Case xlSheetHidden ' do nothing
            Case xlSheetVeryHidden
                If Not VeryHiddenFound Then
                    Set coll = New Collection
                    VeryHiddenFound = True
                End If
                coll.Add sh.Name
            End Select
            n = n + 1
            SheetNames(n) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If n = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheet found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not VisibleFound Then
        MsgBox "No visible sheet found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If n < shCount Then ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To n) ' n - actual count
    
    If VeryHiddenFound Then ' convert to hidden
        For Each Item In coll
            wb.Sheets(Item).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Next Item
    End If
    
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Copy ' copy to new workbook
    
    If VeryHiddenFound Then ' revert to very hidden
        Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        For Each Item In coll
            wb.Sheets(Item).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            dwb.Sheets(Item).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Next Item
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Sheets exported: " & n, vbInformation

End Sub


Sub ExportSheetsTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ExportSheets wb, Array("DO NOT SAVE")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the following snippet:

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name <> "DO NOT SAVE" Then
         Dim rng As Range
         Windows("SOURCE WORKBOOK").Activate
         rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells
         rng.Copy Before:=Workbooks("TARGET WORKBOOK").Sheets(i)
      End If

   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are right! Now this should work without Select